# Google Sheets Formula To Add Column Names As Column Entries Based On Condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a sheet with the following columns. Im trying to add another column and use a formula that where there is an X the column name is inserted to the genre column. I tried a lookup and some IF statements but couldn't nail it down. Im sure some nested IF statements? thank you stack praise be the overflow gods.

```
    A          B          C         D           E        F
title_name   genre      sports    action     comedy   history
Ted Lasso                 X                    X
```

So it would look like this

```
    A               B               C         D           E        F 
title_name       genre            sports    action     comedy.  history
Ted Lasso   sports, comedy           X                    X
```

Comment: Right now I've just added 22 blank columns (no of genres) used this formula =IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",Y$1) and dragged it across the empty cells then Ill merge the new cells with the genre names into one. Bit convoluted would still like a shorter way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=textjoin(", ",true,filter($C$2:$F$2,C3:F3="X"))
```

Comment: that's neat works like a charm thanks a bunch. Nice addition to the tool belt, ill play around with it.

Comment: Good to know. Have a look at the documentation for the two formulas to learn more about them.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(C2:F="",,C1:F1&",")),,9^9))), ",$", ))
```

[image]